# How to compare a text file data with the sql server table data . The comparison i want record to record

Tags: javascript, java, sql-server

I have a text file and a database connection i.e. SQL Server. What I want is to compare records of the file and the database.

I’m looking for a solution that can help me to compare individual records instead of creating a temporary table in db or create a file from database records and then compare it.

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL_Query);
                    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
                    String aName = rsMetaData.getTableName(1);
                    System.out.println(aName);
                    int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
                   // System.out.println("resultSet MetaData column Count = " + numberOfColumns);
                    while(rs.next()) 
                    {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {


                      // get the designated column's table name.
                        String ColumnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);            
                    //System.out.print( ColumnName + " = ");
                    String ColumnValue = rs.getString(i);
                   // System.out.println(ColumnValue+"\t");

                    map.put(ColumnName, ColumnValue);
                    }
                    //System.out.println();

                    } 

                 // retrieve all key pairs present in a Table


                  //Retrieving the number of key-value pairs

                    System.out.println("the number of key-value pairs: "+map.size()+"\n");

                    // retrieve all key-value pairs present in a Table

                    Set<Entry<String, String>> keyValueSet = map.entrySet();

                    for (Entry<String, String> entry : keyValueSet) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
                    }
```

Text file structure find below.

ORIGINATING_SYSTEM_ID|CFI_CODE|CUSIP|DESCRIPTION1|
PHEWyJJHNvnw    |DBFGBR |037833100  |GB0000424886

Answer (score 0):

Well, since DB have a search engine faster than comparising objects in the java memory... I will recommend you, to create the temporary table.

If not, just load objects from the file and by primary key, search in the DB if the record exist and then compare the fields that you want.

If you want more detailed solutions, you should specify the technologies you are using.

**EDIT, PROPOSED SOLUTION:**

Load the  file and query against BD by id, if match, then compare fields

Supposing that its a "CSV" file, and each line has an entry:

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("your path file"));
  String SQL_Query = " SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE ORIGINATING_SYSTEM_ID = '"
  while(r.hasNextLine()) {
       String fields[] = r.nextLine().split("|");
       if(fields.length>0 && !"ORIGINATING_SYSTEM_ID".equals(fields[0])){
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL_Query + fields[0] + "'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(fields[0]) 
                    && fields[0].equals(rs.getString("ORIGINATING_SYSTEM_ID"))
                 //Fields comparation...
                 //Another workaround to this(programatically better) is define a model, and map the values in it
             }
       }
  }
  scanner.close();
```

Comment: I’m using java with IDE JDK1.8 and database Sql server.

Comment: I’m new to this to compare database records and a file records.

Comment: Please help me with the second solution in which you told me to load the objects and compare. Please help me if you can explain me with a short example. Thanks in advance

Comment: No currently doing it standalone.

Comment: Currently i’ Able to read the data from database in key-value pair using hashmap. But now getting only one record from the table. If i need to get all the records corresponding to a particular key, how may i get this

Comment: Can you post your code? So I can see what you have done?

Comment: map.put(ColumnName, ColumnValue);
        }
        //System.out.println();

              } 
        
     // retrieve all key pairs present in a Table
      //Retrieving the number of key-value pairs
        System.out.println("the number of key-value pairs: "+map.size()+"\n");
    // retrieve all key-value pairs present in a Table
    Set<Entry<String, String>> keyValueSet = map.entrySet();
            
           for (Entry<String, String> entry : keyValueSet) 
           {
               System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
           }

Comment: Currently I have fetched the record from database using hashmap now I want to validate with the records with the text file. should I convert my text file to JSON Object to validate each record?

Comment: add the code, by editing your initial post, the whole code, or atleast starting from the resultset. And how is structured your text file, if its a CSV, or just text plain, how do you identifie the fields inside your file...

Comment: @jasbirmalik soultion added in my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ramon. it helps me a lot . could you do me a one more favour. here we are using only "ORIGINATING_SYSTEM_ID" . If i have to fetch the all the records from the table and validate with all the records of text file. how could i make changes in the If condition. thanks in advance

Comment: you have to know what is the primary key of the table, of there isn't a  primary key?
This is to query the records that i guessed have the same primay key of the record that is from the file.
If you want to validate all the records for each record of the file, it will increase a lot the time performance.

Comment: ok so what is the other best way to validate a file records with the database table. other way i have taken the database records in hashmap. so now I'm not sure what exactly i need to do so i can compare these two records(between source file and database target table).  @Roman may i use like 1st convert file to hashmap then compare or i need to put the file in the temporary database table then compare these two temporary table and main target table.  thanks in advance

Comment: i have created two connections one is with file and another is with database using list and comparing these two. Is it correct?